# A simple script to allow sorting of custom posts in admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I found this on wordpress.org forums. tested it and works fine. When i changed the variables to my own it failed. I checked it thoroughly (!) for hours. i can't see where it's going wrong.

```
register_post_type( 'book', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Books',
        'singular_name' => 'Book',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit book',
        'edit' => 'Edit',
        'new_item' => 'New Book',
        'view_item' => 'View Book',
        'search_items' => 'Search Books',
        'not_found' => 'No books found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No books found in Trash',
        'view' => 'View Book'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag')
    )
);
register_taxonomy(
    'book_category',
    'book',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Categoriën',
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'rewrite' => Array(
            'slug' => 'book_category')
        )
);
function add_new_columns($defaults) {
    $defaults['book_cats'] = __('Categoriën');
    return $defaults;
}
function add_column_data( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'book_cats' ) {
        $_posttype  = 'book';
        $_taxonomy  = 'book_category';
        $terms      = get_the_terms( $post_id, $_taxonomy );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
            $out = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $c )
                $_taxonomy_title = esc_html(sanitize_term_field('name', $c->name, $c->term_id, 'category', 'display'));
                $out[] = "<a href='edit.php?book_category=$_taxonomy_title&post_type=$_posttype'>$_taxonomy_title</a>";
            echo join( ', ', $out );
        }
        else {
            _e('Uncategorized');
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_book_posts_columns', 'add_new_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_column_data', 10, 2 ); ?>
```

My edited version (the newly "adjusted" one that now does something!):

```
register_post_type( 'frog', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Frog',
        'singular_name' => 'Frog',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New frog',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit frog',
        'edit' => 'Edit',
        'new_item' => 'New frog',
        'view_item' => 'View frog',
        'search_items' => 'Search frogs',
        'not_found' => 'No frogs found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No frogs found in Trash',
        'view' => 'View frog'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag')
    )
);
register_taxonomy(
    'frog_category',
    'frog',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Categories',
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'rewrite' => Array(
            'slug' => 'frog_category')
        )
);
function add_new_frogcolumns($defaults) {
    $defaults['frog_cats'] = __('Categories');
    return $defaults; //missing as pointed out by scribu
}
function add_frogcolumn_data( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'frog_cats' ) {
        $_posttype  = 'frog';
        $_taxonomy  = 'frog_category';
        $terms      = get_the_terms( $post_id, $_taxonomy );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
            $out = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $c )
                $_taxonomy_title = esc_html(sanitize_term_field('name', $c->name, $c->term_id, 'category', 'display'));
                $out[] = "<a href='edit.php?frog_category=$_taxonomy_title&post_type=$_posttype'>$_taxonomy_title</a>";
            echo join( ', ', $out );
        }
        else {
            _e('Uncategorized');
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_frog_posts_columns', 'add_new_frogcolumns' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_frogcolumn_data', 10, 2 );//this line was also wrong
```

Comment: That script doesn't allow sorting, just displaying a custom column. Also, is that the original script or the modified one?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49947/10691) — it enforces ordering on both front-end and backend.

Answer (score 1):

That script doesn't allow sorting, just displaying a custom column. Is that the original script or the modified one?

Note that register_post_type() and register_taxonomy() shouldn't be called directly, but in a callback hooked to the 'init' action. Working version:

```
function my_init() {
    register_post_type( 'frog', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Frog',
            'singular_name' => 'Frog',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New frog',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit frog',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'new_item' => 'New frog',
            'view_item' => 'View frog',
            'search_items' => 'Search frogs',
            'not_found' => 'No frogs found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No frogs found in Trash',
            'view' => 'View frog'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag')
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
        'frog_category',
        'frog',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Categories',
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'rewrite' => Array(
                'slug' => 'frog_category')
            )
    );
}

function add_new_frogcolumns($defaults) {
    $defaults['frog_cats'] = __('Categories');//frog_cats relates to? 
    return $defaults;
}
function add_frogcolumn_data( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'frog_cats' ) {
        $_posttype  = 'frog';
        $_taxonomy  = 'frog_category';
        $terms      = get_the_terms( $post_id, $_taxonomy );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
            $out = array();
            foreach ( $terms as $c )
                $_taxonomy_title = esc_html(sanitize_term_field('name', $c->name, $c->term_id, 'category', 'display'));
                $out[] = "<a href='edit.php?frog_category=$_taxonomy_title&post_type=$_posttype'>$_taxonomy_title</a>";
            echo join( ', ', $out );
        }
        else {
            _e('Uncategorized');
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'my_init');
add_filter( 'manage_frog_posts_columns', 'add_new_frogcolumns' );
add_action( 'manage_frog_custom_column', 'add_frogcolumn_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It's the original from here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-taxonomies-filter-in-manage-posts?replies=6 Yeh lack of a function, that did look strange. It does sort though for me, but only when unsullied.

Comment: Well, not much we can do to help if we can't see the faulty version.

Comment: i've added the faulty version and tried to add an image of the original working. Not sure if the image hosting is awake though...

Comment: hmm, not getting very far with this. Shame it's not more straightforward. Great having custom post types but sorting them in the admin is quite a nightmare

Comment: Oh, you're missing `return $defaults` in add_new_frogcolumns(). See updated answer.

Comment: Got it at last! The line- add_action( 'manage_frog_custom_column', 'add_frogcolumn_data', 10, 2 );
should be- add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_frogcolumn_data', 10, 2 ); as  manage_posts_custom_column appears to be a wordpress hook that populates the columns with taxonomy links. I might be talking drivel but it works now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Having said that it still doesn't like the custom posts and taxonomies i intended it for. The types are imgPost and imgGallery , note the camel case! is that a problem? I wonder if these are being sanitized, how do i work around that? rebuilding the posts would be a slog to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but i stumbled here via google.  i was looking for something else, but in case anyone needs it:

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-post-type-columns

is some really great info on how to add custom columns for CPTs.  strange looking website but some totally badass WP info.

and this is one of justin tadlock's tuts.. and it goes a step further to making things sortable.  [Custom columns for custom post types](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types)

i'm finding that only *some* columns are sortable.. i think b/c it is a modified query.  i have yet to figure out how to sort by taxonomy like i'd like.