# How to bring an old edited/modified post in the front of page?

Tags: posts

Is there a way to bring, automaticaly, an old edited/modified post in the front of page?

More clear, I want that every time when i edit a post to display it in front of my page, like sticky posts or something.

Is that possible?

**Edit**

First, thanks for your promptly answer!

Yes, in part this is it, but it's not exactly what I want.

**This function add posts in front of my page and it's OK:**

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=modified&order=desc'); ?>
```

but, in addition, I would like this to happen in sidebar too, in "*recent posts widget*" and in "*Featured Posts Grid*", it's the Featured Content Slider that i use it.

**This function doesn't work for me, i don't know why:**

```
<?php 
function wpse10691_alter_query( $query ) 
{ 
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_search() || $query->is_archive() )  ) 
    { 
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' ); 
        $query->set( 'order', 'desc' ); 
    } 
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse10691_alter_query' ); 
?>
```

Comment: Paloma - you will need to remove the `query_posts` it's over-riding what you set at `pre_get_posts`.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you want to order posts by their modified date.

If so, then this should be a solution:
[How to order posts by modified date without using 'query_posts'?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49940/how-to-order-posts-by-modified-date-without-using-query-posts/49947#49947)

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM SOLVED !**

This is the solution:

```
function wpse10691_alter_query( $query ) 
{ 
    { 
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' ); 
        $query->set( 'order', 'desc' ); 
    } 
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse10691_alter_query' );
```

Thanks, guys!